# Join Expression Not Support on Inner Join and Left Join Query

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to have my query pull data to include all dates from my one tbl_actual even though there is no data for certain dates in my tbl_planned.

But when using my Inner Join and my Left Join together, it is saying that the Left Join is not supported.

I have tried to use two inner joins instead of a left join, but that still only pulls dates from the tbl_planned query, I need all dates from tbl_actual too

```
SELECT cal.Day, planned.LocalDay, actual.LocDay, actual.Over30Minutes, 
actual.Over30MinutesHours, actual.NumOfUses, actual.TotalDurationTaken, 
planned.Campaign, planned.Supervisor, planned.DurationScheduled, 
actual.PersonID, planned.PersonID


FROM (tbl_actual AS actual INNER JOIN tbl_planned AS planned ON 
(planned.PersonID = actual.PersonID)) Left Join tbl_actual ON actual.LocDay 
= planned.LocalDay
```

Comment: Your logic is quite strange, because you are joining the same table twice.  Can you provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to have my query pull data to include all dates from my one tbl_actual even though there is no data for certain dates in my tbl_planned.

In SQL, this can be expressed as `tbl_actual LEFT JOIN tbl_planned`, followed by the joining conditions (date and person). Records in `tbl_actual` with no match in `tbl_planned` will still be included in the output, with all columns related to `tbl_planned` showing `NULL`.

I guess that your query could just be simplified as follows :

```
SELECT 
    -- cal.Day,
    planned.LocalDay,
    actual.LocDay,
    actual.Over30Minutes, 
    actual.Over30MinutesHours, 
    actual.NumOfUses, 
    actual.TotalDurationTaken, 
    planned.Campaign, 
    planned.Supervisor, 
    planned.DurationScheduled, 
    actual.PersonID, 
    planned.PersonID
FROM 
    bl_actual AS actual
    LEFT JOIN tbl_planned 
        ON  planned.PersonID = actual.PersonID
        AND actual.LocDay    = planned.LocalDay
```

PS : what is table alias `cal`, as shown in `cal.Day`, the first column of your resultset ? This alias is not declared anywhere in the query, I commented out the column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to refer `tbl_actual` only once:

```
FROM tbl_actual AS actual INNER JOIN
     tbl_planned AS planned
     ON planned.PersonID = actual.PersonID AND
        actual.LocDay = planned.LocalDay
```